# Javafx snapshot makes video frame becomes scrambled

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

With JAVAFX I am trying to take a snaphot of a `MediaView` using the `snapshot()` method.

The `MediaView` displays a paused video frame.

The issue is that the first time I take the snapshot the video frame becomes scrambled. By resizing the view manually in my app the view becomes coherent again.

Is there a way to quickly overcome this problem? I tried to progrmatically resize but it didn't help :-(

Comment: resizing it programatically works...
But if there is a better solution I'd like to know

Comment: perhaps I should say that the main window is swt...